# Unable to read and process large txt files using threading, background worker or string builder

Tags: vb.net

In .net I'm coding an app that needs to read large txt files, such as 10 mb. My problem is  reading files using StreamReader and doing some string manipulation, and then adding the results to a list box.

If I use threading or a background worker, processing becomes very slow. I also tried using string builder but with same result.

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Use the `BackgroundWorker` to keep your app from getting stuck. Use good code to keep the background process from being so slow. You're going to have to put some effort into describing what you want to accomplish and what you've tried before you can get any more specific help.

Comment: can u put more details into how u want to manipulate?

Answer (score 1):

You can read a 10 mb text file very quickly using ReadAllLines:

```
Dim ss() As String
ss = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
```

Then you can manipulate the strings in the array, `ss` in this case.

When you update the ListBox, you should use .BeginUpdate and .EndUpdate to make that part faster.

You can put Application.DoEvents in the loop to allow Windows messages to be processed. This may keep it from looking so much like the system is locked up.

Comment: Before you start adding a lot of items to the ListBox, call the method `ListBox1.BeginUpdate()`. After you're finished, call `ListBox1.EndUpdate()`